# Use of Vector Cross in Ms Excel - 3D arrays and Redim

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, vba

I'm facing an issue with the use of Redim in VBA of MS Excel in a 3D array. How can I append a new array with different dimension than the first one to the first array and then another one and then ...; and then be able to read a specific group of data from this newly created matrix (array) with different number of columns in each row, for example, the 2nd group of data. Here is an example to clarify the matter.

- Arr1 is in 3x3
- Arr2 is in 5x5
- Arr3 is in 7x7
- Arr4 is in 9x9
- Arr5 is in 11x11 dimensions.

Now if I append them together the resulting matrix should be in this format - for example:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 1
2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 1 2
3 4 5 6 7
...
...
1 2 3  ... 11
1 2 3  ... 11
(another 8 rows)
1 2 3  ... 11
(total of 11 rows)

Next I want to be able to read a group of data (sub-matrix) from the resulting matrix, for example the 2nd group of data, which is in 5x5.
If I use Redim in between each loop, while appending those new group of arrays and so to adjust the dimensions of the first matrix and continuing to do so, the last dimension will be in 11x11, which does not give me the needed dimension; in this case 5x5.

I was wondering, if there is any recommendation you could kindly provide. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the code you've attempted.

Comment: You are describing 2-D arrays, not 3-D arrays.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I added another dimension to each matrix to make it a unique group/set of data. So, when for example p = 1, the first outcome-matrix is 3x3, and when p=2, it is about the second matrix which is the 5x5 matrix and so on. so the first cell will be (1,1,1), and the seond cell on right will be (1,1,2) ...and the last cell will be (5,11,11).